# How do I override the toString method to display elements in a list in Java?

Tags: java

I have been trying to figure this out for hours, but I am unable find an answer that works.

For completeness, I have posted the entire code below.  If I do not Override the toString method, I get the representation for the hashcode for the object.

I tried using the following:

```
 public  String toString(List<?> list) {
String result = " ";
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        result += " " + list.get(i);
    }
    return result;
}
```

However, this does not seem to help as I still get a reference to the hashcode. I understand that this is because I am not overriding the toString method properly; I get an error when I include the @Override annotation, but this is as far as I have been able to get.

I looked at some other answers that said that overriding the toString method would not be useful in the case of Lists/Collections, but no proper guidance for another alternative was given.

```
public class WordsContainer {
Collection<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();

public void wordGroup1() {
    wordList.add("Ant");
    wordList.add("Almond");
    /// more words
  }

public Collection<String> getRandomWords() {
    wordGroup1();
    LinkedList<String> wordLinkedList = new LinkedList<String>(wordList);
    ArrayList<String> subList = new ArrayList<String>();

    int i = 0;
    while (i < 6) {
        int index = (int) Math.random() * 10;
        if (!subList.contains(wordLinkedList.get(index))) {
            subList.add(wordLinkedList.get(index));
            i++;
        }
    }
    return subList;
}

public  String toString(List<?> list) {
String result = " ";
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        result += " " + list.get(i);
      }
    return result;
    }
 }

public class wordsContainerTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    wordsContainer list1 = new wordsContainer();

    list1.wordGroup1(); 

    System.out.println(list1);

  }


}
```

EDIT :

Apologies, I forgot to mention that I tried removing the parameters in the Override method like this:

```
public  String toString() {
  LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<>()
   String result = " ";
   for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    result += " " + list.get(i);
}
return result;
```

}
But when I ran the code, the console displayed nothing. I realize this is because I instantiated an empty list, but I at this point, I didnt know what else to do.

Comment: Just stop taking a parameter into your `toString()` method. `toString() ` should print a representation of the class which means the list should be inside the class which means you shouldn't have to pass it in.

Comment: When your goal is to override a method, annotate your method with @Override. So that, if you're not actually overriding anything (which is the case here), you'll get an error from the compiler. Look at the javadoc of Object.toString(). Your method is supposed to have the same signature.

Comment: Of course: you're iterating on a new empty LinkedList you create in toString(). You want to iterate on `wordList` instead. Also, when you post code, post code that actually compiles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`toString()` has no arguments. Overwrite it like so (assuming you are extending a List class):

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    String result = " ";
    for (int i = 0; i < this.size(); i++) {
        result += " " + this.get(i);
    }
    return result;
}
```

**UPDATE 01**

Ok, it seems that what you really want to do is print the contents of the list that is encapsulated by your WordsContainer.

Override toString of WordsContainer like so:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(" "); // remove this if you do not want two spaces at the front of the returned string
    for (int i = 0; i < this.wordList.size(); i++) {
        sb.append(" " + this.wordList.get(i).toString());
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Note that you have to change the declaration of wordList to be of type `List<String>`.

**UPDATE 02**

This answers the followup question in comments.

You can declare a static utility method that builds a string representation of the contents of any given list of strings like so:

```
public static String getStringRepresentation(List<String> list) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(" "); // remove this if you do not want two spaces at the front of the returned string
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        sb.append(" " + list.get(i).toString());
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

And use this method like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("foo");
    list.add("bar");
    String listStringRepr = WordsContainer.getStringRepresentation(list);
    System.out.println(listStringRepr);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean extending List class (not to mention that List is an interface) ?

Comment: As OP is attempting to override the toString implementation of some list, I assume he is extending some list implementation, e.g. ArrayList.

Comment: @QuakeCore OP has created `public class WordsContainer` which is not implementing `List` (neither extending any abstract class). It's a new Class. So,  the `toString()` method of `Object` class is being overridden here

Comment: Yes, @QuakeCore, Saud is right, I am not implementing List as an interface, but is that my only course of action?

Comment: The issue here is that your question doesn't really match what you actually want to do. Let me update the answer, I think I now understand what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you for the swift response; I think you meant public String toString instead of public void? 

In any case, I tried the updated approach, and I am now able to print out a  list. However, if I also want to print out a list of random words too, would I have to add another caveat to the toString method? Is there a way for me to Override the toString method such that I am able to print out any list without having to modify toString repeatedly?

Comment: Correct, I messed up the return type, sorry. It should of course be public String toString.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel: `return list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(" "));`

Comment: @user2430656 Updated answer with an answer to your followup question.

Comment: @Bohemian: clever, didn't know that one :)

Comment: OP here, 

What you are saying is that all the elements in the list should be added in main instead; I want to keep the main as short as possible.

Also, I do not understand the use of the getStringRepresentation method, as I am adding my code in main, and only invoking that method to print out the list. It seems more efficient to simply use System.out.println(list) at this point.

Thank you very much for your detailed answers by the way.

Comment: @Frosty619 I'm not really sure what you are asking. Adding the elements in main was simply done in order to demonstrate how you could use the getStringRepresentation method to produce a string representation of any given list of strings. If the answer helped you find a solution, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: If what you want to do is combine it to a single line, you can of course also write System.out.println(WordsContainer.getStringRepresentation(list));. This is simply a matter of style - there is absolutely no difference in terms performance.

Comment: Thankyou! You have been very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You do not match the signature of `Object.toString()`. (I usually let my IDE generate a stub, helps plenty ;))

Just add this to your existing code:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "WordsContainer{" +
            "wordList=(" + toString(wordList) + ")}";
}
```

Though, you will have to declare `wordList` as `List`.

**UPDATE:**

To clarify the last remark in the original answer:

In your own wrapper `WordsContainer` you declare `wordList` as

```
Collection<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

while in your own attempt at implementing `toString` you use `List<?>` as parameter type. Therefore, the above code would not work without one other refactoring. Either declare `wordList` as `List<String>`

```
List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

or refactor your `toString()` to take a `Collection<?>` as argument:

```
public String toString(Collection<?> list) {
    String result = " ";

    for (Object item : list) {
        result += " " + item.toString();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: It's not permitted to instantiate the object as list as its an interface, so I am not sure I am following.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have provide parameter to your `toString()` method, it is no more the `Object`'s class `toString()` method. It is a new method and works as a overloaded version of `Object`'s `toString()` not the overridden version. Remove the parameter. To work the `toString()` properly you need to have the exactly same method signature -

```
public String toString(){
   //implmentation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call toString() with the List element itself. 
Like so:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.LinkedList;
public class WordList {
    List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
    public static void main(String []args) {
       System.out.println(new WordList());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String result = "";
        list.add("Hello");

        list.add("World");
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            result += " " + list.get(i).toString();//call toString on element of the list
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Output: ' Hello World'

Answer (score 0):

```
package listtostringmethod;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
public class ListToStringMethod {

    enter code here
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        //List<String> s = Arrays.asList("a","b","c");
        //s.toString();

        MyList myList = new MyList();
            myList.add("a");
            myList.add("b");
        //myList.toString();
        System.out.println(myList.toString());
    }

}

class MyList extends ArrayList {
    @Override
    public String toString (){
        StringBuffer retVal = new StringBuffer();
        Iterator iterator = this.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()){
                retVal.append(iterator.next()+",");
            }
        return retVal.toString();
    }
}
```

The code is straight forward. Hope this helps you.